# Drupal 7 core cookies

Tags: cookies, drupal-7

In the default installation of drupal (7.2.3), what cookies are set by the system.
I'm looking to gather a list of all cookies set, any help would be grateful.

Comment: That depends on the what modules you are using. See drupal_set_cookie calls in api.drupal.org. Also there is a has_js cookie set from JavaScript I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar issue and looking at api.drupal.org did help, in the end, as all I needed was to get list of cookies set on the front end of the site, I  used fire bug and checked what cookies were being set there.